# How to extract the very first frame of a second in a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract the first frame of a second from a video. I have tried different ways to achieve this, but I failed. Here the commands I tried.

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -s 400x222 -q:v 3 -start_number 0 -vf fps=1 %d.jpg
```

Later, I am trying to extract the frames again using the below command of that particular second. Here I'm extracting the frames of 210th second.

```
ffmpeg -ss 210 -i input.ts -s 300x250 -t 1 -start_number 0 images.%d.jpg
```

I want to extract only the starting frame of the second. Let's say from 0.001 of that particular second.

When I compare the frame of 210 second extracted by my first command with the first frame extracted by second command are completely different.

For the later use, to prevent the conflicts I want to extract only the very first frame of the original input video. I tried using the command which was told by stackoverflow experts in the past [here](https://superuser.com/a/1010108). But when I run it. It is only extracting the starting frame(only 1 frame).

How can I extract the very starting frame of the video per every second?

Comment: Do you want the first frame of every second? means if your frame rate is 25 fps then you want 1 frame out of 25 at every second am i right?

Comment: @Milan yes. You got it exactly.

Answer (score 2):

try this command :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=between(mod(n\, 25)\, 0\, 0), setpts=N/24/TB" output-%04d.png
```

you have to pass your video framerate or `fps` in `between(mod(n\, 25)\, 0\, 0)` my video fps is `25` so i pass 25

if your fps 60 then you have to pass 60 in `between(mod(n\, 60)\, 0\, 0)`

also if you want 1st 5 frames of every second then use `between(mod(n\, 25)\, 0\, 4)` it will give your 1st 5 frames of every second.

Comment: Won't be reliable for VFR streams. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1389062) for a generic expression.

Comment: @Milan I have tried using your command, but when I re run the second command in my question(i.e extracting the frames again for that particular second) the frames are different at the 0th frame. Both frames generated by 1st and 2nd command are different.

Comment: you also want to extract a frame from particular second of video am I right?

Comment: @MilanTejani yes. I want the 0th frame of my both commands should be same.

Comment: @Gyan any solution for this?

Comment: @MilanTejani your command is not working for a live growing input file.

Comment: @MilanTejani have you got any updates regarding the command to work on live feed?

Comment: @Gyan what is the need of that, setpts option in this command?

Comment: Not my command, but it's usually to make timestamps of selected frames regular (without gaps) so ffmpeg does not duplicate frames. `24` should be replaced with `FR`

Comment: Why did you set the setpts value to N/24/TB? Whats the meaning of that?