# Extract the 0th frame of every second on a live video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a command to extract the zero-th frame of every second. I got the command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033432/12624423).

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "select=between(mod(n\, 25)\, 0\, 0), setpts=N/24/TB" output-%04d.png
```

But when I run the above command on live feed, it is extracting more than 100000 frames. The above command is not working on a live recording. Can anyone suggest or help me to extract the very first frame on a live recording? Thanks in advance.

P.S: For my testing I am running the above command on a tcr video.

Comment: Adapt this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1389062

Comment: @Gyan It is extracting the frames, but they are not in the sync.

Comment: Not clear what that means.

Comment: I played the video in VLC, stopped at 200th second. Compared it to the 200th frame. The frame on the player and the 200th frame are not the same. FYI I am using 25FPS tcr time code video to check. I made that video coming as live input in chunks.

Comment: @Gyan wll the command you shared work for any framerate?

Comment: Yes. If the video is VFR, then 200th frame can represent a time greater than 200s.

Comment: @Gyan I used the command as you suggested, -vf "select='if(not(floor(mod(t,1)))*lt(ld(1),1),st(1,1)+st(2,n)+st(3,t));if(eq(ld(1),1)*lt(n,ld(2)+1),1,if(trunc(t-ld(3)),st(1,0)))'" -vsync 0 but the frames, extracted are not in the sync as I said earlier. Input is a .ts file.

Comment: @Gyan can we use pts options? can you suggest on how to use it here?

Comment: @Gyan the command you said was extracting only 3460 frames. Not extracting the frames for every second.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))'" -vsync 0 output-%04d.png
```

This will output the first frame of each second, if it exists.

Comment: Share full report of `ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))',showinfo" -vsync 0 output-%04d.png`

Comment: sorry, I was using some wrong command. It is extracting 3600 frames exactly. But will it extract the frame naming from 0 or 1?

Comment: When I ran it through the time code tcr video, it is extracting one frame per every 25 frames, irrespective of the input file FPS. My actual input file frame rate is 29.97. But it is extractig one frame per every 25 frames.

Comment: It will extract the first frame of every second. Doesn't matter what the fps is.

Comment: it is NOT extracting the zero-th frame not even in Non-LIVE files. It is extracting 12th frame of every second, both on LIVE and on Non-LIVE.

Comment: MPEG-TS usually start with a non-zero timestamp, so if you're checking on absolute timestamps, add -copyts because ffmpeg by default normalizes input timestamps to start from zero.

Comment: So, you are saying that, adding that ` -copyts` option after -vsync 0?

Comment: It's a global option so anywhere.

Comment: It extracted the 0th frame for first second. But for remaining all seconds, it extracted the 8th frame, right from the 2nd second.

Comment: You can see the images and the followed images in this link. https://ibb.co/KwL5rsG

Comment: You can see the images and the followed images in this link. https://ibb.co/KwL5rsG in this link, you can see the extracted frames in the order from 00:42:00.00, it has extracted the first frame correctly with its 0th frame, But from the next second, it has extracted the 00:42:01.19 and then 00:42:02.19 and so on, It is sometimes extracting the 19th frame and 8th frame randomly but not extracting the 0th frame. I even added the option -copyts.

Comment: Share an input file.

Comment: Please find the input video I am trying, in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7jQZgYDuMD71DWb53T5AJGcx5Vbw0Pv/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Works as expected. See report and images at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4UdiWshXa56dXJf8b4-uZNrnoiZNhOw/view?usp=sharing. In report, see command on line 5 and output timestamps on lines starting with `[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 00000000039efc40] n`

Comment: I have got the frames properly like, getting the 0th frame for some of the seconds but not for all the seconds. After the 30th min or after 40th min, they are going a bit out of sync, and from there I am getting 00:30:00.08, 00:30:01.08 and after a while, getting 00:40:00.13 and 00:40:01.13 like this. I hope you checked for the whole video, not just starting portion of the video. Just making sure, nothing else.

Comment: Also, I hope you are trying and encoding it as the live video file, not as the recorded file.

Comment: I extracted from the entire file, and I only see TCRs ending with `:00`.

Comment: it is extracting the frames wrongly for the live growing video. If I try to extract the frames for the already recorded video, it is extracting properly. But I need the 0th frame to be extracted for every second.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the command. The timestamps and the TCR in t he growing input aren't aligned as you think they are.

Comment: How can we handle if the LIVE input has the dropped frames?

Comment: can you suggest any other options to handle the frames extraction? Currently on live 0th frame is NOT extracting for every second.

Comment: This is not working properly for 29.97 and 59.94 FPS videos.