# ffmpeg - script to extract 1st frame of each second with deinterlacing

Tags: ffmpeg, scripting

i'm trying to write a shell script to analyse some videos by using the first frame of each second of video as a basis. i'm using ffmpeg to extract the frames. i thought i'd hit gold when [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031043/how-to-extract-the-very-first-frame-of-a-second-in-a-video-using-ffmpeg) came up in my searches, but it doesn't handle the deinterlacing.

i'm using a time-based approach that works well for various formats as long as the video is progressive. it doesn't work so well for interlaced video (only the first field is output in that case, creating a half-height image). i've tried various combinations of deinterlacing (`yadif/bwdif`) with `select` but the filter chains i create either cause errors or still return a half-sized image.

here is my call w/a filter that works correctly for progressive video source :
`ffmpeg -i $infile -vf "select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))" -vsync 0 $outfile`

the following still return only half-height images for interlaced source :
`... -vf "bwdif=0,select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))'"`

`... -vf "bwdif=0,select='between(mod(n\,$ips)\,1\,2)'"` *-- $ips is images per second*

`... -vf "select='between(mod(n\,$ips)\,1\,2)',bwdif=0"`

i've also tried various permutations of the above w/explicit frame reference (`-r`, `-vframes`, ...), still no joy.

can someone help me with the syntax ?

**--EDIT--**
*here is the complete output of running the command with the first filter :*

```
ffmpeg version N-104925-gfe95731e3d-g68457c1e85+3 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --pkg-config=pkgconf --cc='ccache gcc' --cxx='ccache g++' --ld='ccache g++' --disable-autodetect --enable-amf --enable-bzlib --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-iconv --enable-lzma --enable-nvenc --enable-zlib --enable-sdl2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libaom --disable-debug --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-fontconfig --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmfx --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libshine --enable-gpl --enable-avisynth --enable-libxvid --enable-libopenmpt --enable-version3 --enable-librav1e --enable-libsrt --enable-libgsm --enable-libvmaf --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-chromaprint --enable-decklink --enable-frei0r --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libilbc --enable-libsvthevc --enable-libsvtvp9 --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmodplug --enable-librist --enable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libtesseract --enable-libxavs --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-libcodec2 --enable-ladspa --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-openssl --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-libs=-lstdc++ --extra-cflags=-DCACA_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DMODPLUG_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DCHROMAPRINT_NODLL --extra-libs=-lstdc++ --extra-cflags=-DZMQ_STATIC --extra-libs=-lpsapi --extra-cflags=-DLIBXML_STATIC --extra-libs=-liconv --disable-w32threads --extra-cflags=-DKVZ_STATIC_LIB --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-DAL_LIBTYPE_STATIC --extra-cflags='-IC:/ffab/local64/include' --extra-cflags='-IC:/ffab/local64/include/AL'
  libavutil      57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100
  libavcodec     59. 14.100 / 59. 14.100
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 20.100 /  8. 20.100
  libswscale      6.  1.101 /  6.  1.101
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Passing a number to -vsync is deprecated, use a string argument as described in the manual.
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mxf, from 'mire-720-576-16-9.mxf':
  Metadata:
    operational_pattern_ul: 060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010900
    product_uid     : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0002
    uid             : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000
    generation_uid  : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001
    company_name    : FFmpeg
    product_name    : OP1a Muxer
    product_version_num: 58.38.100.0.0
    product_version : 58.38.100
    toolkit_version_num: 58.38.100.0.0
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001375063852947134C97506380052947134C97500
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:02:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 55987 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: jpeg2000, yuv422p10le(top first), 720x288, lossless, SAR 32:45 DAR 16:9, 50 tbr, 50 tbn
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001375063852947134C97506380052947134C97501
      track_name      : Picture
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001375063852947134C97506380052947134C97501
      track_name      : Sound
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (jpeg2000 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'testout%04d.png':
  Metadata:
    operational_pattern_ul: 060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010900
    product_uid     : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0002
    uid             : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000
    generation_uid  : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001375063852947134C97506380052947134C97500
    product_version_num: 58.38.100.0.0
    toolkit_version_num: 58.38.100.0.0
    encoder         : Lavf59.10.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb48be(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 720x288 [SAR 32:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbn
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001375063852947134C97506380052947134C97501
      track_name      : Picture
      encoder         : Lavc59.14.100 png
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    2 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.02 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0177x    
frame=    3 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.02 bitrate=N/A speed=0.617x    
frame=    4 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.02 bitrate=N/A speed=0.938x    
frame=    5 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.13x    
frame=    6 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.26x    
frame=    6 fps=1.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.09x    
frame=    7 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.19x    
frame=    8 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.27x    
frame=    9 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.33x    
frame=   10 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.38x    
frame=   11 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.43x    
frame=   12 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.47x    
frame=   13 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.5x    
frame=   14 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.53x    
frame=   15 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.56x    
frame=   16 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.58x    
frame=   17 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.6x    
frame=   18 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:16.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.62x    
frame=   19 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.63x    
frame=   20 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:18.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.64x    
frame=   21 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:19.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.65x    
frame=   22 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:20.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.66x    
frame=   22 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:20.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.59x    
frame=   24 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:22.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=   25 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:23.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=   25 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:23.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.64x    
frame=   26 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:24.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.65x    
frame=   27 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:25.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.66x    
frame=   28 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:26.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.67x    
frame=   29 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:27.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.68x    
frame=   30 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:28.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.68x    
frame=   31 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:29.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=   32 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:30.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=   33 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:31.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=   34 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:32.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.71x    
frame=   35 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:33.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=   36 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:34.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=   37 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:35.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=   37 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:35.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=   38 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:36.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=   39 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:37.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=   40 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:38.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=   41 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:39.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.71x    
frame=   42 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:40.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.71x    
frame=   43 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:41.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=   44 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:42.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=   45 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:43.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=   46 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:44.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=   47 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:45.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.74x    
frame=   48 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:46.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.74x    
frame=   49 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:47.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=   50 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:48.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=   50 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:48.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=   51 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:49.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=   52 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:50.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=   53 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:51.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=   54 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:52.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=   55 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:53.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.74x    
frame=   56 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:54.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.74x    
frame=   57 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:55.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=   58 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:56.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=   60 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:58.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.78x    
frame=   61 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:59.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.79x    
frame=   63 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:01.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.82x    
frame=   64 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:02.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.82x    
frame=   65 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:03.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.82x    
frame=   67 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:05.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.85x    
frame=   68 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:06.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.86x    
frame=   69 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:07.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.86x    
frame=   71 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:09.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.89x    
frame=   72 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:10.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.89x    
frame=   73 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:11.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.89x    
frame=   74 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:12.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.89x    
frame=   75 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:13.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.89x    
frame=   77 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:15.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   78 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:16.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   79 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:17.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   80 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:18.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   81 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:19.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   82 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:20.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   83 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:21.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   84 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:22.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   85 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:23.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   86 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:24.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   89 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:27.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.97x    
frame=   90 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:28.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.96x    
frame=   90 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:28.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.94x    
frame=   91 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:29.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.94x    
frame=   92 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:30.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.94x    
frame=   92 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:30.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   93 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:31.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   94 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:32.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x    
frame=   94 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:32.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.9x    
frame=   95 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:33.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.9x    
frame=   95 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:33.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.88x    
frame=   96 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:34.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.88x    
frame=   96 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:34.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.86x    
frame=   97 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:35.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.86x    
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:36.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.86x    
frame=   98 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:36.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.84x    
frame=   99 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:37.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.84x    
frame=   99 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:37.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.83x    
frame=  100 fps=1.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:38.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.83x    
frame=  100 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:38.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.81x    
frame=  101 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:39.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.81x    
frame=  102 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:40.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.81x    
frame=  102 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:40.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.79x    
frame=  103 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:41.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.8x    
frame=  103 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:41.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.78x    
frame=  104 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:42.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.78x    
frame=  105 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:43.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.78x    
frame=  105 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:43.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.76x    
frame=  106 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:44.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.76x    
frame=  106 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:44.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=  107 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:45.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=  108 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:46.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.75x    
frame=  108 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:46.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.74x    
frame=  109 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:47.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.74x    
frame=  109 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:47.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.72x    
frame=  110 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:48.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=  111 fps=1.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:49.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.73x    
frame=  111 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:49.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.71x    
frame=  112 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:50.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.71x    
frame=  112 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:50.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=  113 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:51.02 bitrate=N/A speed= 1.7x    
frame=  113 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:51.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=  114 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:52.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=  115 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:53.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.69x    
frame=  115 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:53.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.68x    
frame=  116 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:54.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.68x    
frame=  116 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:54.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.67x    
frame=  117 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:55.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.67x    
frame=  117 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:55.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.66x    
frame=  118 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:56.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.66x    
frame=  118 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:56.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.65x    
frame=  119 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:57.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.65x    
frame=  120 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:58.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.65x    
frame=  120 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:58.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.63x    
frame=  120 fps=1.7 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:59.02 bitrate=N/A speed=1.64x    
video:43029kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Share full log for first bwdif filter attempt.

Comment: thanks @Gyan, i've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is detected as interlaced but with half-height (288) and double the framerate (50). This may be due to missing or unrecognized boundary markers in the JPEG2000 packets. I assume this is meant to be PAL --> 720x576@25i.

Try using the [tinterlace](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tinterlace) filter first to interleave the input "frames" to double-height and half fps, and then continue the original sequence of filters.

`"tinterlace=mode=merge,bwdif=0,select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))'"`

Comment: wonderful !  thank you, @gyan, tinterlace was the key.